# How to enable bluetooth when it is disable inside my code?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I made an application with two activities. The first activity imports user parameters and the second activity sends data via bluetooth. I use `.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` to enable bluetooth if it is disabled but when bt is closed my apk exits. It doesn't work. Any help?

I use this; code on create activity and after start handler and runnnable... I test it only findBT and work...

```
 void findBT()
 {
  mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
  {
      myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
  }

  if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
  {
      //My problem is there
      Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
      startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
  }

  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
  if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
  {
      for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
      {
          if(device.getName().equals(strValue2))
          {
              mmDevice = device;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean your application is crashing by "apk exit"?

Comment: hey shreya do u have any about bluetooth API ... :)

Answer (score 5):

here is the code :

```
 public class AndroidBluetooth extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView stateBluetooth;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        stateBluetooth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bluetoothstate);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        CheckBlueToothState();
    }

    private void CheckBlueToothState(){
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
            stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT support");
        }else{
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");
                }else{
                    stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled.");
                }
            }else{
                stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is NOT Enabled!");
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            CheckBlueToothState();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Ok.What is REQUEST_ENABLE_BT?How i declare it?

Comment: Bluetooth admin permission when needed?

Comment: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" give this in ur Manifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

This code to check your device is BlueTooth enabled or not:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
Toast.makeText(this.getParent(), ConfigClass.BLUETOOTH_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Check and Enable your Bluetooth :

```
else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: Its my constant class...U can write your own message at that place...let me know If you need any other functionality info